# How to Get an id in jsp instead of value?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

how to get button id from jsp to servlet instead of getting the button value

```
<input id="${section.id}" type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit">
```

how to get that id in servlet?

Answer (score 6):

You can't that id is for client side use only. You will need to set the `name` or `value` to match the id of the element.

Alternatively as a workaround you could create a hidden input field that contains the id value by adding something like this to your JSP:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit_id" value="${section.id}" />
```

This will then be available in the servlet upon form submit under the `submit_id` parameter.

```
String submitId = (String)request.getParameter("submit_id");
```

Comment: this is my code 

'<input id="${section.id }" type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit">'

how to get that id

Comment: Add the hidden input field as shown in my answer and you can get the id from the servlet under the submit_id parameter

Answer (score 1):

The only way you would be able to do that is by intercepting the form submit using javascript and setting the id as an extra post/get parameter.

Answer (score 0):

the only way is make a javascript function that change your button value for the id , but i dont know why you want to do that, you could use a hidden input to send the data in the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="the_id_number" />
```

Comment: this is my code 

'<input id="${section.id }" type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit">'

how to get that id

Comment: if you use jquery you could do something like $("input[type=submit]").click(function(){ $(this).val($(this).attr("id")); } ); , but this is going to affect all submit button, you can use a class name or id name on the jquery, but again, the best solution is send this info over hidden inputs

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get any button id value to servlet. When a request from browser is submitted, all the input fields(input tag) will be transferred to server.The value of each input attribute can be accessed using the name of that field.All other fields like id, class etc are used for css and JavaScript functionalists.You should not design to pass the button id to server side.Think of other methods like hidden input fields